# WCF Generate help for REST POST call

Tags: wcf, rest

Using WCF, it is possible to generate help for a webHTTPBinding. With a WebGet operation, it works like charm. Using a WebInvoke (Method = "POST") however doesn't give me any help. In the pages I can see this:

> Url:
>   http://localhost/edumatic3/trunk/services/service.svc/rest/saveUser
>
> HTTP Method: POST
>
> Message direction Format  Body
>
> Request           Unknown Could not generate schema document.
>
> Response          Unknown Could not generate schema document.

Any ideas?

Web.Config system.serviceModel

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="HelpEndPointBehavior">
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
           customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=      
           "Edu3.Service.OpenApi.Security.CustomUserNameValidator
           , Edu3.Service.OpenApi" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="OpenApiService" 
             behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="soap" 
              address="soap" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="Edu3.Service.OpenApi.Interface.IService" 
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration"/>
    <endpoint name="rest" 
              address="rest" 
              behaviorConfiguration="HelpEndPointBehavior"      
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="Edu3.Service.OpenApi.Interface.IService"/>
    <endpoint name="mex"  
              address="mex" 
              binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  
                           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="services/service.svc" 
         service="OpenApiService" 
         factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Service Contract:
The GetNodeByKey gives me clear help. The SaveUser not.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "login?userName={userName}&password={password}")]
    void Login(string userName, string password);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getNodeByKey/{key}?getAllDescendants={getAllDescendants}"
        , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(BranchNodeDTO))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(LeafNodeDTO))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(CasusNodeDTO))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(BucketNodeDTO))]
    NodeDTO GetNodeByKey(string key, string getAllDescendants);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "saveUser", Method = "POST"
        , BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    UserDto SaveUser(UserDto user, int channelId);
}
```

Comment: How do your operation and data contracts for request and response look like?

Comment: I've edited the question with system.serviceModel and ServiceContract.

Comment: Will it work if you remove `channelId` from the `SaveUser` (just for test) and make the body style `Bare`?

Answer (score 2):

What about your DataContract? Are there any enums which have FlagsAttribute? It seems that when you use **[Flags]** WCF isn't able to correctly generate the help page.

**Source:** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020406/en-us